# WebApi ActionFilterAttribute, HttpActionContext access user name (IPrincipal)

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, actionfilterattribute, iprincipal

**I need to access the currently logged in user in my action filter**. The identity is set by a `DelegatingHandler` further up the chain of execution.

**I *can* access the current `IPrincipal` using `HttpContext.Current.User`.**
So far I avoided using `HttpContext.Current` as it appeared to me to be bad style.
First of all your code will only work if hosted in IIS and secondly it includes a reference to `System.Web` which I guess doesn't hurt but I'd prefer to stick with `System.Net.Http` if possible.
*It just feels wrong to rely on good old "`HttpContext`"*.

**Is there any other way to access the user's identity within an `ActionFilter`? Or is it okay to use `HttpContext` if you don't plan on running a self hosted application?**

Comment: Damn.. I really really searched thoroughly before posting the question. 5min later I have two working answers :(

Answer (score 17):

I overlooked the obvious. I didn't realize there was a Controller property inside the `ControllerContext`.

```
var username = ((ApiController)context.ControllerContext.Controller).User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: in Web API v2 `actionContext.RequestContext.Principal` will do the trick.